# Spring 3.0.3 REST and security

Tags: spring, rest, security

How do I secure Spring 3.0.3 REST ? May I use Spring Security 3 (using authenticationManager similar to [sprint-rest security](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/spring-security-on-rest-api/))  ?

Comment: That is a very theoretical question. Have you checked the documentation of the said technology?

Comment: Yes. Want to make sure how compatible using Sprint 3.0.3 REST with security 3.0. I do not want to run into issues later. Per documentation, i see section B.2 Authentication Services:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html . Can an expert confirm this?